# Parameter is null depending on xml format

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have this class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName= "buyer-accepts-marketing")]
    public bool BuyerAcceptsMarketing { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName= "closed-at")]
    public DateTime? ClosedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And this simple Controller with this method I'm using to test the Request:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Order order)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

When I run the service locally and post this xml to the service using Fiddler:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">false</buyer-accepts-marketing>
</order>`

I receive the parameter in the Controller's Post method and everything is ok.
However, if I post the xml with the second property:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">false</buyer-accepts-marketing>
  <closed-at type="datetime" nil="true"></closed-at>
</order>`

The parameter `order` arrives null in the Controller's method.

I'm probably doing something wrong in the xml or in "mapping" of the class, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: I can see you are not sending closed-at in xml.where is the value of datetime?

Answer (score 0):

You have placed your [`nil`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx) attribute in the default namespace.  You need to put it in the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace.  The conventional way to do this is to put it in the root element with the `xsi` prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">false</buyer-accepts-marketing>
  <closed-at type="datetime" xsi:nil="true"></closed-at>
</order>
```

But it would be semantically identical to put it on the `"closed-at"` element itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order >
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type="boolean">false</buyer-accepts-marketing>
  <closed-at xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="datetime" i:nil="true"></closed-at>
</order>
```

Since the `DateTime? ClosedAt` is not null (because it does not have a proper `xsi:nil="true"` attribute) but also cannot be deserialzed as a `DateTime` (because the value is empty), `XmlSerializer` gets confused and throws an exception.

**Update**

If you cannot change the XML to contain a [standard representation for a null `DateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/#Nils), you will need to implement a proxy property to do the conversion manually.  Since you didn't specify in your question whether you need to serialize back as well as deserialize, the following does both:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "buyer-accepts-marketing")]
    public bool BuyerAcceptsMarketing { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? ClosedAt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("closed-at")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlDateTimeWrapper XmlDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return ClosedAt;
        }
        set
        {
            ClosedAt = value;
        }
    }
}

public class XmlDateTimeWrapper
{
    public static implicit operator DateTime?(XmlDateTimeWrapper wrapper) { return wrapper == null ? null : wrapper.DateTime; }

    public static implicit operator XmlDateTimeWrapper(DateTime? dateTime) { return new XmlDateTimeWrapper { DateTime = dateTime }; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string DateTimeString
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateTime == null)
                return string.Empty;
            return XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                DateTime = null;
            else
                DateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get { return "datetime"; } set { /* Do nothing */ } }

    [XmlAttribute("nil")]
    public bool Nil { get { return DateTime == null; } set { /* Do nothing */ } }
}
```

If you never need to serialize back, you could use a string-valued proxy property:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "buyer-accepts-marketing")]
    public bool BuyerAcceptsMarketing { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? ClosedAt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("closed-at")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string XmlDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return ClosedAt == null ? null : XmlConvert.ToString(ClosedAt.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                ClosedAt = null;
            else
                ClosedAt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwswer! The problem is that I do not have access to alter this xml. It will come in this format(with a little more nodes). What could I do in this case?

Comment: @gabsferreira - Can you share what those extra nodes look like?  Is there an [XSD schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) provided?